# Help understanding how to factor completely $x^3-x^2-x+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I need someone to help explain the steps to completely factor the problem $x^3-x^2-x+1$.

Here is what I have done so far:

> $x^3-x^2-x+1$
>
> to
>
> $x^3-x^2+-1(x+1)$
>
> Since there is a negative I changed $-x+1$ to $-1(x+1)$
>
> to
>
> $x^2(x-1)+-1(x+1)$
>
> to
>
> $(x^2-1)(x-1)(x+1)$.

Is this correct? If not please explain what I did wrong and what I should do. If it is then thank you for saying so, if not, thank you for helping me to understand.

Comment: $-1(x+1)=-x-1\neq -x+1$.

Comment: And you got a polynomial of degree $4$ out of a polynomial of degree $3$.

Comment: One can guess 1 as one zero of the polynomial and get a polynomial of degree 2 by polynomial division. The divisor is (x-1). The resulting polynomial of degree 2 can be solved by the standard method. This way one finds all prime factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^3-x^2-x+1$. By Rational Root Theorem, any rational root $\frac{p}{q}$ of $g(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ has $p\mid a_0$ and $q\mid a_n$ (i.e. $q$ divides $a_n$). Proof is simple: substitute $x=\frac{p}{q}$, multiply both sides by $q^n$, observe divisibility.

Since $f(1)=0$, we know $x^3-x^2-x+1=(x-1)P(x)$ for some $P(x)$, which of course must be quadratic, so $P(x)=x^2+ax+b$.

$$(x-1)(x^2+ax+b)=x^3+(a-1) x^2+(b-a)x-b=x^3-x^2-x+1$$

So $a-1=-1, b-a=-1, -b=1$, so $b=-1, a=0$.

$$x^3-x^2-x+1=(x-1)(x^2-1)$$

Comment: why would i be using f(x)? should i only be using that if I'm am trying to solve x? I have never seen my professor do that before for a factoring problem. What is it that i am not understanding?

Comment: @SprJD7903 that is just created notation for the function, which lets me claim $1$ is a root of it just by saying $f(1)=0$. You could avoid defining the function and say "$x^3-x^2-x+1=0$ when $x=1$, so $x^3-x^2-x+1=(x-1)P(x)$ for some $P(x)$".

Answer (score 3):

$$x^3 - x^2 - x + 1 \to x^2(x - 1) + (-1)(x-1)$$
$$\to (x-1)(x^2 - 1) \to (x-1)^2(x+1)$$

Comment: why is there an equal sign and two "(x^2-1)" s? its making it difficult for me to understand your steps

Comment: All of the above statements are equal. Each statement represents it's own step

Comment: @SprJD7903 $(x-1)(x^2-1)=(x-1)(x-1)(x+1)=(x-1)^2(x+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Simply notice that $x=1$ is a root. Hence by Ruffini your polynomial $x^3-x^2-x+1$ is divisible by $x-1$. Thus there exists a second degree polynomial $p(x)$ (you can find by a simple polynomial division) such that $x^3-x^2-x+1=(x-1)p(x)$. Being $p$ of degree $2$ you can easily find its roots with the well known $\Delta$ formula, in order to factorize completely your polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

we want to factor the polynomial $\mathbb{P}=x^{3}-x^{2}-x+1$

factor out $x^2$ to start as follows;
$\mathbb{P}=x^2(x-1)-(x-1)$

This makes sense because if you expand above you would get, $x^3-x^2-(x-1)=x^3-x^2-x+1$ which is of the form you had at the start.

Now factor out $(x-1)$

$$=(x-1)(x^2-1^2)$$

It may be helpful to see it as,

$(x-1)(x^2-1)$ say we call $(x-1)=a$ then you can see above on the second line for example we had $ax^2-a$. So to factor out a, can you see that it would be $a(x^2-1)$

I added the square because of the next step, and it does not change the one of course. 
Now, we know that $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$ You can expand this to see that it is true if you like.

so $(x^2-1^2)=(x-1)(x+1)$

so $\mathbb{P}=(x-1)(x-1)(x+1)=(x-1)^2(x+1)$

Of course there are other ways that the polynomial can be factored, but this seems to be the nicest final form

Comment: That's some amazing algrebra...  Can you walk through those steps in a little more detail?

Comment: Sure I added some

Comment: But $x^2-x-1 \neq (x-1)(x-1)$  I think you meant $x(x-1)-1$

Comment: I meant that I have never seen $x^2-x-1=(x-1)(x-1)=(x-1)^2$ before... how does it work?

Comment: Oh yea , I meant was ross had corrected , sorry about that i will fix

Comment: i can't follow it, from what i can see in your 3rd step is that you have factored it down to (x+1)(x-1)(x-1). Shouldn't this be the answer then? Where is the -2x and -2x^2 coming from?

Comment: SprJD, try the second approach, I think it is better

Comment: @Quality, what is the second approach that you are referring too?

Comment: Where I say, " Another way which may be better"

Comment: It is not at all obvious to me how to go from the third line to the fourth.  I think your "Approach 2" is much better.

Comment: Thanks Ross, I will just include my second approach

Comment: @Quality, when you get to  ℙ=x^2(x−1)−(x−1) , wouldn't you just set it to (x^-1)(x-1)^2 ? I don't mean to pester you and i really appreciate you taking your time to come back here each time i ask questions, I really need to understand this.

Comment: @SprJD7903 No problem don't worry about it, just ask if you don't understand.  And you wouldn't because they (x-1) are not being multiplied by each other at that step, the second (x-1) is there because it had no x^2 to have factored out of it,

Answer (score -2):

\begin{align}x^3-x^2-x+1&=x^3-x^2-x+1+(3x^2-3x^2)+(3x-3x)\\
&=x^3+3x^2+3x+1-x^2-x-3x^2-3x\\
&=(x+1)^3-4x^2-4x\\
&=(x+1)^3-4x(x+1)\\
&=(x+1)\left[(x+1)^2-4x\right]\\
&=(x+1)(x-1)^2\end{align}

Comment: what in the world? where in the world are these other numbers coming from? Are you using a predetermined equation? can you list it?

Comment: This answer relies on $(x+1)^3=x^3+3x^2+3x+1$ and $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$.  This leads to $(x+1)^2-4x=x^2+2x+1-4x=x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2$.